# SSIS automate insert upate excel file format issue

Tags: sql, ssis

i have to insert and update some values which is daily coming from 
excel file but as everyday excel file format is different 
so tell me other possible ways to automate insert update ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the excel files really in different formats or does Excel just think they are different? If the columns are still in the same ordinal positions but they are being interpreted as having different data types, then yes, you can provide hints to the driver to overcome.

Otherwise, you could use C#/vb.net and query the worksheet, dump that into an dataset, write that to a variable and then shred that object but it's ugly. In fact, dealing with Excel in a programmatic fashion is always ugly and best avoided.

Comment: Example link for which, first or second solution?

Answer (score 0):

If your file is a different format each day then you are out of luck.  That is a problem, and there is really no easy or efficient way to parse and insert/update based on that.  Whatever the source of the data is, you need to ensure that it becomes consistent.

If it is a *handful* of formats that you can test and handle accordingly then you could always have some data flow logic inside the SSIS package, but if this isn't predetermined then you would have no way of handling these cases.

Comment: files are in excel format but format differs i can use same package for every file :( please suggest ways

Comment: @ashuthinks I should have verified this before.  What do you mean by format?  Do you mean file format or data format?  Are you talking about *.csv/*.xls/*.xlsx or the way the data is placed in the file for retrieval?

Comment: yes i'm taking about data which is in excel file ... everytime data chages its position from excel sheets

Answer (score -1):

YOu deal with this by returning the file to the provider and requiring them to provide in the same fashion every day. Then your SSIS pacakge should reject the file if it is not in the correct format. While you aer at it you will have far fewer problems if they send .txt or .csv file. Excel support is exceedingly poor.

Comment: so what else i can do? convert files into csv or txt but data is changing it position every day :(